# Refresh the page automatically if a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code but it for only a page. I want do it for all links.

```
$('.row').on("click",".nav_link",function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel click
  var page = $(this).attr('href');   
  $('.row').load(page);
});
```

Comment: every link on the page or every link with `nav_link` class

Comment: Try https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

Comment: I'm using it on blogger. Please code sample. @zabusa

Comment: Do you need to prevent refresh on links with `.nav_link` only?

Comment: @Madhavan.V for all "a" links?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to load the pages. You can do something like:

```
$(function(){
  $(".nav_link").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var ajx = $.ajax({
      url: url
    }); 

    ajx.done(function(d){
      $(".row").html(d);
    });
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="https://fiddle.jshell.net" class="nav_link">Click Me</a>
<div class="row"></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iVoidWarranties/e5awk21a/)

Comment: And, Can I use it with "a" tag?